# Edits to borderline spam answers can possibly interfere with audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

Okay, so I *just* reviewed an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50269622/4909087) in the LQP queue. This answer had been marked as spam and deleted.

I presume the reason for this is because of the fact that they'd added their contact info into their post in (presumably) good faith which was later edited out by another user. The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50269622/revisions) shows this:

[image]

You can see that the post was edited before it was deleted.

Now, looking at the meat and potatoes of the answer, it doesn't look all that bad to me. At least, what was left after Glorfindel's edit certainly is NOT spam to me. As part of my [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19906384), I carefully read through the question below, and the answer, visited all the links, and decided it wasn't worth deleting.

But I was told to "STOP! Look and Listen". Even though that's *exactly* what I did. I reviewed the context of the question and took many things into consideration before deciding. And, it appears that [I wasn't the only one who was tripped up here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368945/edits-to-borderline-spam-answers-can-possibly-interfere-with-audits#comment596855_368945).

The point I'm trying to make here, is that the edit made interfered with the audit. My biggest disappointment is that it is going to count as a strike against me for no real reason. It has also resulted in a 3 day review ban. ;-(

This thread is mainly meant to start a discussion on the audit system, but you may consider it a feature request of sorts. I believe the spam flags were issued on the version *before* the edit. To that end, I would request that audits should display the versions of the answer on which the flag is raised. Or, if that is too hard to implement, then don't show answers with non-trivial edit histories. It opens up avenues to misunderstandings like this. This was borderline in my opinion, and I don't really think it should've been deleted to begin with.

Comment: At least as far as regular users, who don't have domain or user-specific knowledge (i.e. can't tell if the answer's correct or if this user has a pattern of bad posts), are concerned, even the initial version should not be marked as spam (even though I can see why people would flag it as such). ... unless our motto is "delete everything that remotely looks like spam, even if it's useful". I see this more as motivation to add a formal process for invalidating audits, or to improve the audit selection process in general.

Comment: It should be easy enough to just not select for audit posts that have been edited (rather than trying to show users the "right" version of the post).

Comment: Well it wasnt just you who tripped on this one. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50269622/timeline

Comment: @SurajRao great, that link really nails it in, thank you.

Comment: I'm pedantic: That answer didn't get deleted due to spam flags, just 3 nasty 20K-ers clicked the delete link. That the content got spam deleted must be due to a spam flag it got. The [post](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/118987) did show up in [CharcoalHQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=44520401) and [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42476022) and got autoflagged but due to the false positive feedback the autoflaggers [got pinged](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44520426#44520426) to retract their flags.

Comment: Maybe the audit queue could work both ways? If an abnormal amount of people get tripped in the audit queue, that gets queued for attention for possible undeletion / review?

Comment: @rene Did I get this right? You consider yourself nasty?

Comment: @KamiKaze I thought it was wise to be open about it upfront instead of waiting for being tarred and feathered by others as often is the case with those who moderate posts ... you decide for yourself.

Comment: @rene Agreed sometimes it gets to be a witchhunt for simple slip-ups.

Comment: We get like 20 posts like this one each week. Just stop reviewing until they fix the hopelessly broken audits. Seriously. Nothing less will ever make fixing this crap a priority. Until the audits are fixed, SO staff can do the reviews themselves.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I agree that the original revision shouldn't be flagged as spam and I've disputed all the spam flags on the answer. It should no longer be a review audit.

Although review bans are automatically handed out not just based on one recent audit failure, I have lifted your review ban in good faith.