# I fail to understand how this answer is spam or offensive

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20107506) audit. I was then banned from review.

The text of the answer is:

> There's no negative to using 301's or 302's anymore, and especially so if you're migrating to https from http.
>
> I guess the only thing to be considerate of is to use the correct 3xx code just to adhere to best practices, though by and large Google doesn't really care.

[image]

I fail to understand how this answer is "spam or offensive". To be clear, this isn't really a high quality answer, but the LQP review queue isn't about high quality answers versus low quality answers at all, it's for weeding out *very* low quality posts - "thanks", blatant Spam, link-only answers, "I'm having this problem too" comments, "How about them Mets?", posts critiquing the question-asker's mother, etc.

Could I get clarification on what in this post indicates that "readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful"? If failing to post the best answer a person can possibly post is now "the new Rude", I don't know *what* is Rude anymore.

It looks like the answer *was* edited and it is thus *possible* that there was some obvious Spam or Rude content that was edited out, but then first of all I do not have access to review the history of a deleted post (and also, it didn't appear necessary to investigate whether or not the post was deleted *at all* because the post was so obviously at least a reasonable, non-VLQ *attempt* to answer), and second of all it was edited by a *moderator*, and Spam and Rude are supposed to be *unsalvageable* posts by definition. We have been told time and time again not to turd-polish, so I would not expect a moderator to be doing so.

Comment: What do the revisions look like?

Comment: @Daedalus I don't know, I don't have access to them. :( If viewing the revision history is necessary in order to make the correct review decision, then it is only fair that access should be provided. Also, I thought we were supposed to be reviewing the most recent version of the post, *especially* if the most recent revision corrects issues that the post may have had in the past (and possibly resulted in now-invalid flags).

Comment: I almost wish there was some sort of mod-only checkbox to remove a question from automated audit generation, so that cases like this don't happen.  There is probably some history here neither of us is aware of, given a mod did edit the post in question.

Comment: Yeah there was a spam link in that answer that was then removed by a moderator. This was a serial spammer. Just one of those days. I forget why the spam link gets edited out for serial spam - I agree there isn't much of a point in doing so when the spam/offensive filter hides the content for you.

Comment: I think I remember this one. I'm traveling now, I'll add an answer about that when I reach home.

Comment: try to add a spam link at the end like the original "answer" was. Now you see that this text is just vague blurb just to avoid being detected by bots as "link only" followed by spam link. But easy to tell with the link :)

Comment: There's related feature request for [audit to show the versions of the answer on which the flag is raised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368945/edits-to-borderline-spam-answers-can-possibly-interfere-with-audits)

Comment: While Bhargav explained this one, it's important to remember that [spam/rude flags do not end the grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307637/end-the-edit-grace-period-upon-two-or-more-spam-rude-flags-being-raised), so its possible a question gets voted out with flags, but gets edited just before the last vote is cast. As it's within the grace period, it wouldn't show in edits. It's one of those rare gotchas

Answer (score 73):

I handled that flag there, I remember that post because I came back to it after handling and then rehandled it.

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953682/thousands-of-301-redirects-bad-for-seo/50577306#50577306) was flagged as spam by a couple of users. It was posted by a new user, whose profile didn't contain any spammy links. I did a google search to figure out if the useful content in the answer was plagiarized, but it wasn't. There was just a dangling spam link at the end of the post. I figured out that the users had flagged it because of that. I thought (mistook) that the poster was naive, and added the link as an example. Therefore I removed it and marked the flags as disputed. I went ahead and closed the question, as it was not on topic.

However it was reflagged as spam, and I saw that reflag some 5 minutes later. I realized that there *might* have been some mistake by me, and spent more time on it. I did a google search of that with "quotes" and then [figured that it was indeed plagiarized](https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/5pnt3i/what_is_the_impact_of_too_many_301_redirection/). That domain [was also spammed earlier on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237525/what-is-the-best-apartment-management-software-available-for-maintaining-a-resid). Therefore I flagged that as spam, and then destroyed the user.

What I did not do was, rollback my changes. I didn't rollback because, rolling back a post would clear the spam flags on that revision. However, I did not realize that it'd turn out to haunt me again as an audit.

I'm sorry for this mistake of mine, I'll remember it in future.

> We have been told time and time again not to turd-polish, so I would not expect a moderator to be doing so.

[Turd polishing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=turd-polishing) is a bit different from this, and I do agree with the advice to not turd-polish.

Comment: Thanks, could you remove my review ban?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot. The night's been a bit long. Done.